# ownCloud Docker File Synchronization

Tags: docker, owncloud

installed ownCloud with docker as following:

```
docker pull owncloud  
docker run -v /var/www/owncloud:/var/www/html -d -p 80:80 owncloud
```

that works. Setup a client with access to server, works also.

Following issue: when i copy a file by *command line* to the volume it is copied to the container (also good), **BUT MY CLIENTS ARE NOT SYNCED**. It looks that clients are only synced, if the webinterface is used.

Any idea, how to fix this?

thanks ralfg

Comment: I don't think that clients are updated if you copy a file directly to a physical ownCloud server either. How would ownCloud know that something has happened (unless it polls or listens to events from the server file system, normally wasted resources)? Use one of the clients or the web interface.

Comment: i'm using owncloud without docker since 2 years; use case written above is working correctly (syncing) with locally installed owncloud ....